# Is there anyway to hold response until we get full response from server in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

The services I'm trying to test will work on a long pooling method.

They won't give results in the first response.

When I run my API script I am not getting a full response in the first time.

How can I wait in this case for the remaining portion of the response to be received?

I want to use values from this response into the next call.

[image]

In the above screen, my response should wait when complete: True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor/) as a child of the request which returns the above response and configure it like:

   [image]
2. Put your request under the [While Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) and use the following [__jexl3()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) function as the condition:

   ```
   ${__jexl3("${complete}" != "true",)}
   ```

   [image]
3. That's it, While Controller will continue executing its children until the condition is met:

   [image]

Comment: Is there a timer guarding the while so it doesn't get stuck in an endless loop ?

Comment: Nope, but you can add an extra clause to your condition to i.e. make not more than 10 iterations of the While Controller